# What does "to charge up" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Here they come ten thousand strong
>   **Charging up** the hill
>   This day will be both hard and long
>   They move in for the kill
>
> Hold the line, don't let it break
>   Use your sword and spear
>   A glory death, for all awaits
>   All who knows no fear

Could you please explain what means "to charge up" in these lyrics from 'Free Will Sacrifice' by Amon Amarth? My best guess is that it's just a metaphor. But perhaps there is a special and rarely used meaning of this verb?

Comment: They are simply charging to the top of the hill, "up" is there because there's a hill and they are moving to the top of it, so moving in an upward motion. And of course it's not charge as is charge your phone or charge money for something, it is **charge - to move forward quickly and violently**

Comment: So "to charge" here just means "to attack"?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: charge up means move quickly - they intend to attack

Comment: You can charge up the hill, down the hill.

Comment: Folks voting to close should consider that looking up "charge up" in the dictionary results in a definition that makes no sense: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/charge+up If you don't know that charge has a meaning that works independently of "up" it can be difficult to know what to look up.

Comment: @Rathony I think you're right - I took the lyrics tag off. I'm going to bold the phrase in the passage as well.

Comment: The verb is *charge*. *Up the hill* is a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As MorganFR and Cathy Gartaganis](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/709/commenting-vs-answering/710#710) commented, "to charge" is being used here with the definition of "**to attack by rushing violently against**."

The word "up" is not a part of the phrase "charge up" here, as it would commonly be when using "charge" to mean "*charge up* a battery". Rather, it is simply saying which direction the men were charging- "up the hill." In contrast, the enemy atop the hill could have very well responded by "charging down the hill" at them.

[This scene from the Lord of the Rings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mE328QhF-VA) opens with a group "charging out" of the stronghold and down a narrow walkway, and then later the cavalry, led by Gandalf (in white), "charges down" the hill to fight.

[Also this scene from the Lord of the Rings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8-tZ17TVLM) is the "Charge of the Rohirrim", and the beginning of the actual charge can be seen at 2:10 in the clip.